# Displaying a list as an <option value="">

Tags: javascript, select

Here is my quandary:

I am looking to create a drop down menu that displays a listing of information when selected.

My coding thus far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownTip(value) {
        console.log(value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>

<select onchange="dropdownTip(this.value)">
    <option value="Printer List" selected="" disabled="">Printers</option>
    <option value="Printer A">HP</option>
    <option value="Printer B">Zebra</option>
    <option value="Printer C">Lexmar</option>
    <option value="Printer D">Qual</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Basically what I'm looking to do is:

1. User selects an option value
2. Upon selection of an option value I would have a predefined dataset/list (*see below*) to appear below the dropdown itself.

   > Printer Name: GRHPCOLOR1
   >   IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   >   Paper types: LaserJet only
   >   Service Call: 1(800)XXX-XXXX
3. Once the user selects a different option value then the dataset associated with each new option replaces the previous.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do this somewhat simply?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? It looks like you just need to change `innerHTML = value` to `innerHTML = dataset[value]`, where `dataset` is an object containing the information you want to print, keyed off the values.

Comment: I guess I'm just more lost then I thought I was. I understand the concept but not how to implement it. I'll keep tooling away on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using a switch statement to set the details)

html:

```
<select onchange="dropdownTip()" id="select">
    <option value="Printer List" selected="" disabled="disabled">Printers</option>
    <option value="Printer A">HP</option>
    <option value="Printer B">Zebra</option>
    <option value="Printer C">Lexmar</option>
    <option value="Printer D">Qual</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
    function dropdownTip() {
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var text = "";

    switch (value) {
    case "Printer A":
    text = "<p>your HP text</p>";
    break;
    case "Printer B":
    text = "<p>your Zebra text</p>";
    break;
    case "Printer C":
    text = "<p>your Lexmar text</p>";
    break;
    case "Printer D":
    text = "<p>your Qual text</p>";
    break;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I am looking for! Thank you, now just some minor tweaking

Answer (score 1):

You can create your predefined dataset in form of JSON object and save your data. And use the key of object as same as your option value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var printList = {
    'Printer A' : { Name : 'HP' , Model : 'HP2001'},
    'Printer B' : { Name : 'HP1' , Model : 'HP120434'},
    'Printer C' : { Name : 'HP2' , Model : 'HP22034'},
    'Printer D' : { Name : 'HP3' , Model : 'HP320tr3'}
    };

    function dropdownTip(value) {

        console.log(value);
        var displayHTML ='value';
        displayHTML += '</br>Name='+printList[value].Name+'</br>';
        displayHTML += 'Model='+printList[value].Model;

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = displayHTML;
    }
</script>

<select onchange="dropdownTip(this.value)">
    <option value="Printer List" selected="" disabled="disabled">Printers</option>
    <option value="Printer A">HP</option>
    <option value="Printer B">Zebra</option>
    <option value="Printer C">Lexmar</option>
    <option value="Printer D">Qual</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

This is the simplest way to show the result from predefined dataset.

Comment: I understand that. But that isn't my issue. My problem is that instead of displaying the value defined within the <option> I want my system to kick back a listing of information predefined about the 'printer' in question...

Comment: Is the predefined information about the 'printer' is saved into some backend DB....and you want to fetch data from DB?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onChange` option for `<select>`

```
<select onchange="yourfunction()"></select>
```

Comment: my bad, I forgot to type what I was using there.

Currently I have:

    <select onchage="dropdownTip(this.value)">

Comment: My issue isn't getting the values into the dropdown menu itself. What I'm looking for is the list of 4 items I mentioned to display rather than the <option value>

Comment: you need array of printers then `var printers = {'Printer A': 'Printer Name: GRHPCOLOR1 IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Paper types: LaserJet only Service Call: 1(800)XXX-XXXX', 'Printer B' ... } `and then `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = printers[value];`

Comment: I guess I'm more lost than I thought... I'm not sure how to implement that into my code.. I guess it's time for trial and error.